# Spring security- ant matcher with hasRole is not working

Tags: spring, security, authorization

I have configured my authorization for pages using method from WebSecurityConfigAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    super.configure(auth);
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //super.configure(http);
    http.servletApi().rolePrefix("");
    http
      .logout()
          .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/patient/mobile.mvc").hasRole("USER_PATIENT").and().formLogin();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/registration/**").hasRole("USER_RECEPTIONIST").and().formLogin();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/doctor/**").hasRole("USER_DOCTOR").and().formLogin();
}
```

in my userDetailsService I have the following methods, to give user his credentials:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userEmail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // 1: Check if exist receptionist with given name
    Receptionist receptionist = loginService.getReceptionistByEmail(userEmail);
    if (receptionist != null) {
        return createReceptionistUserDetail(receptionist);
    }
...
}

private UserDetails createReceptionistUserDetail(Receptionist receptionist) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER_RECEPTIONIST"));
    UserDetails ud = new User(receptionist.getEmail(), receptionist.getPasswordHash(), grantedAuthorities);
    return ud;
}
```

I have no problem with normal authentication and access when no roles are checked, but when I have added a access based on roles, any user can't access his webpages.

What could here be wrong implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, seems that the problem is in prefix. It is still not disabled with code above.

When I have changed method in method for:

```
private UserDetails createReceptionistUserDetail(Receptionist receptionist) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER_RECEPTIONIST"));
    UserDetails ud = new User(receptionist.getEmail(), receptionist.getPasswordHash(), grantedAuthorities);
    return ud;
}
```

User can login without problems. I was trying to find a simple solution, but solutions here are not so simply that just using "ROLE_" prefix... :-)